# How can I put chained conditions inside property binding in XML view?

Tags: sapui5, conditional-operator

I have the following code for one of my app views (InvioceList.view.xml).

**Code that works fine:**

```xml
numberState="{= ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 50 ? 'Error' : 'Success'}"
```

The property `numberState` of control `ObjectListItem` allows me to change the color of the invoices amount depending on the rate.

[image: Hello-world app]

However, the code that works is only ruling two colors. I want to do it with three (`Success` for green, `Warning` for yellow and `Error` for red). So in order to do that, I tried with this:

```xml
<ObjectListItem
  numberState="{= ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 20 ? 'Success' : ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 50 ? 'Error' : 'Warning'}"
/>`
```

**Code that doesn't work fine:**

```xml
numberState="{= ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} < 20 ? 'Success' : ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 60 ? 'Error' : 'Warning'}"
```

So since I'm a beginner in this, I can only recognize for now that the conditional statement I'm using is a ternary operator or multiple conditional, but for some reason, it is not working fine when using more than two intervals (maybe syntax).

So I would like to understand what am I doing wrong or what other way can I take to do the same without using that property. I hope some of you can throw me some light on this.

Comment: Let us know if the below answer was helpful to resolve the issue. See _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers?)_

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly:

Your intervals are defined wrong. Right now you have

> If the price is higher than 20, show success. If it's higher than 50, show error. Else show warning.

These statements are checked in exactly this order.

Let's say you have a price of 80.

Is it higher than 20? Yes it is, so show success. No need to check the rest, since the first condition was already a match.

If you want three intervals, don't start with the middle one.

```
<ObjectListItem numberState="{= ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 50 ? 'Error' : 20 >= ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} ? 'Warning' : 'Success' }" />
```

If you do want to start with the middle one, make your condition more strict.

For example, "is it higher than 20 but lower than or equal to 50 then success".

```
<ObjectListItem numberState="{= ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 20 &amp;&amp; ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} &lt;= 50 ? 'Success' : ${invoice>ExtendedPrice} > 50 ? 'Error' : 'Warning' }" />
```

> & and < are special chars in XML, so you have to escape them.

---

But you see, it's hard to debug and hard to read. I'd strongly recommend a [formatter function](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de).

You can debug it (since it's plain JavaScript) and write readable ternary or if/else statements.